# try to build macOS app by pkgbuild, but in preinstall or postinstall it is root, how to change to nomal user and get sudo

Tags: macos, pkgbuild

And I want to install brew in the script. I try to get userlist to change to normal user, but only has root.

Comment: As it is root that runs the preinstall and postinstall scripts, you can switch to another user inside them, BUT, even if you do that, how would you enter the user password (required for sudo) needed to install Homebrew ??? The way to go would be to install Homebrew, then make a package of the installation.

Comment: make a dialog to get psw

Answer (score 0):

I use $USER to get nomal user, and modify the brew install script. Send the password to the install script. It works well. But I dont think its a good solution...

Comment: Just to understand what you're trying to do: Are you adding packages inside an existing homebrew installation ? Are you installing homebrew and some of its packages as a dependency of an other program ?